# Creating 3d object from RGBD and normal maps

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch3d, back-projection

I have RGBD and normal map and I want to reconstruct a 3d object from those maps - I found a link that helps create point cloud from RGBD map ( https://medium.com/yodayoda/from-depth-map-to-point-cloud-7473721d3f ) but I am also interested in assigning surface normals to those but I am not sure how to do that.
I am specifically looking for approach in pytorch3d given RGBD and normal image